# How can I get a C# timer to execute on the same thread that created it?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I want to enable `IMessageFilter` on an Excel Addin I have to write to excel. 
I have taken example from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) which says:

> Message filters are per-thread, so we register this thread as a
>   message filter (not the main thread that the add-in is created on -
>   because that's Excel's main thread

My problem is that my system writes to excel when a timer elapses which results in the writing method being called from a ThreadPool thread which breaks `IMessageFilter` since the excel cannot access the `RetryRejectedCall` part of `IMessageFilter`, because it lives on the caller thread rather than the executing one spawned by the timer.

*So, my question is: is there a way that I can force a timer's Elapsed event to run on the same thread that initialized the timer?*

> EDIT:

My Question is, how do I make `IMessageFilter` catch excel errors when it throws reject/busy?

Thx

Comment: i think this is so simple, just use Thread.Sleep() in a loop and your own condition.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid spinning in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete answer is as follows:

Problem: Class that writes data to excel unable to handle 'busy/reject' response messages from excel.

Solution: Implement `IMessageFilter` interface as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in.aspx)

`IMessageFilter` Definition (from link):

```
namespace ExcelAddinMessageFilter
{
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct INTERFACEINFO
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
            public object punk;
            public Guid iid;
            public ushort wMethod;
        }

        [ComImport, ComConversionLoss, InterfaceType((short)1),
        Guid("00000016-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        public interface IMessageFilter
        {
            [PreserveSig, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall,
                MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            int HandleInComingCall([In] uint dwCallType, [In] IntPtr htaskCaller,
                [In] uint dwTickCount,
                [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] INTERFACEINFO[]
                lpInterfaceInfo);

            [PreserveSig, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall,
                MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            int RetryRejectedCall([In] IntPtr htaskCallee, [In] uint dwTickCount,
                [In] uint dwRejectType);

            [PreserveSig, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall,
                MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
            int MessagePending([In] IntPtr htaskCallee, [In] uint dwTickCount,
                [In] uint dwPendingType);
        }
    }
```

`IMessageFilter` Implementation part of my class (see link):

```
#region IMessageFilter Members

        int ExcelAddinMessageFilter.IMessageFilter.
            HandleInComingCall(uint dwCallType, IntPtr htaskCaller, uint dwTickCount, ExcelAddinMessageFilter.INTERFACEINFO[] lpInterfaceInfo)
        {
            // We're the client, so we won't get HandleInComingCall calls.
            return 1;
        }

        int ExcelAddinMessageFilter.IMessageFilter.
        RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr htaskCallee, uint dwTickCount, uint dwRejectType)
        {
            // The client will get RetryRejectedCall calls when the main Excel
            // thread is blocked. We can handle this by attempting to retry
            // the operation. This will continue to fail so long as Excel is 
            // blocked.
            // As an alternative to simply retrying, we could put up
            // a dialog telling the user to close the other dialog (and the
            // new one) in order to continue - or to tell us if they want to
            // abandon this call
            // Expected return values:
            // -1: The call should be canceled. COM then returns RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED from the original method call.
            // Value >= 0 and <100: The call is to be retried immediately.
            // Value >= 100: COM will wait for this many milliseconds and then retry the call.
            return 1;
        }

        int ExcelAddinMessageFilter.IMessageFilter.
            MessagePending(IntPtr htaskCallee, uint dwTickCount, uint dwPendingType)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        #endregion
```

With the `IMessageFilter` interface defined and implemented, I setup a STA `Thread` and a `Timers.Timer` as follows:

Thread:

```
thread = new Thread(WriteToExcel);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

Timer:

```
timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 2000;
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(StartSTAThread_Handler);
```

where `StartSTAThread_Handler` is defined as:

```
void StartSTAThread_Handler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     thread.Start();
     thread.Join();
     thread = null;
}
```

This thread calls the method I use to write to Excel and handles rejected messages with the `IMessageFilter` interface described above. The last thing I had to do was to fully qualify excel OM references, that is; instead of:

```
Excel.Range rng = app.ActiveSheet.Range["range_name"];
rng.Copy(); // ERRROR: message filter's RetryRejectedCall is NOT called
```

I had to use fully qualified referencing:

```
app.ActiveSheet.Range["range_name"].Copy // OK: calls RetryRejectedCall when excel dialog etc is showing
```

While this seems to work for my needs, it does seem to contradict the "two dot rule" described by another poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects) ...

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Timer.SynchronizingObject` property to marshal event-handler calls that are issued when an interval has elapsed.

Here's from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx):

> When the Elapsed event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component,
>   such as a button, accessing the component through the system-thread
>   pool might result in an exception or just might not work. Avoid this
>   effect by setting SynchronizingObject to a Windows Forms component,
>   which causes the method that handles the Elapsed event to be called on
>   the same thread that the component was created on.

Assuming you are using a WinFrom and you are creating the timer instance from within the main form:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
t.SynchronizingObject = this;
t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
t.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't using a winform - just a plain C# class. With regard to the initial issue, I found the problem that I was referring to excel indirectly *my_range["some_name"].copy* instead of *excel_app.ActiveSheet.range["some_name"].copy*. This seems to violate the "two dot rule" for releasing COM objects as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects ...

Comment: You might want to share your solution here