# Trigger IMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall when using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I am automating Excel. However I've received user reports that sometimes my application (which is running in a separate process from Excel), sometimes will hang indefinitely while calling Excel using COM interop. I think I've nailed it down to lack of an [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-imessagefilter) registered on the calling thread (an STA thread that I start and have control over) so that I can give the user the option to cancel their call.

The `IMessageFilter` seems to be working. I've implemented it and registered it on my calling thread. Now, if I simply jump into VBA and call `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))` (i.e. just block for 30 seconds) then my thread gets notified through the `IMessageFilter.MessagePending()`, which is what I want. However, I am unable to trigger `IMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall()`. Apparently, Excel's `Application.Wait()` does not block its main thread, because I can still call properties and methods while this occurs (but I will get repeated `IMessageFilter.MessagePending()` notifications).

My hypothesis has been that if I just block Excel's UI thread completely, then I can get it to reject the call from my application and notify me through `IMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall()` but no dice. I also tried using `kernel32` to sleep the thread, but that didn't work either - my app just did a blocking wait until the sleep was over and Excel's main thread got its message pump going again.

How can I trigger `IMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall()`, i.e. how can I put Excel in a state where it will reject interop calls? My purpose is to test my app. I've written tests that simulate it but obviously I would like to see the real thing in action.

Relevant posts:

[How can I get a C# timer to execute on the same thread that created it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738059/how-can-i-get-a-c-sharp-timer-to-execute-on-the-same-thread-that-created-it)

[C# Excel interop - how to test if interop object is still working and performing a task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467510/c-sharp-excel-interop-how-to-test-if-interop-object-is-still-working-and-perfo/14482515#14482515)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I trigger IMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall(), i.e. how can I put Excel in a state where it will reject interop calls?

The easiest task is to run a long-running task using VBA macros. Excel will be busy with running a VBA macro and may reject any external calls.

Comment: Putting Excel in an infinite loop was pretty much the first I tried:) Are you proposing that I do work in addition?